# how to do this javascript i don't get output of button

Tags: javascript, html

there is a problem of getting the output and if can help me please help me

```
<!Doctypehtml>
<html>
<title>new html</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="open">click me</button>
<script >
var open1=document.getElementById("open");
var n="hi";
open1.addEventListener("click", function(){
alert(n.length);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert(n.length"hi");` - that's not valid javascript - your developer tools console output would've told you that

Comment: What are you trying to do ? `alert(n.length+"hi");` ?

Comment: `alert(n.length"hi");` is invalid syntax; try `alert(n.length + "hi");`

Comment: `open1.addEventListener("click" function(){` miss a `,` between click and function. Should be `open1.addEventListener("click", function(){` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccna79z4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!Doctypehtml>
   <html>
       <title>new html</title>
       <head></head>
       <body>
           <button id="open">click me</button>
           <script >
           var open1=document.getElementById("open")
           var n="hi";
           open1.addEventListener("click",function(){
               alert(n.length);
           });
           </script>
      </body> 
</html>
```

You have missed the "," after click

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put , after event name:

```
var open1=document.getElementById("open")
var n="hi";
open1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(n.length);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is your updated code: You just missed the comma(,) after "click".

```html
<!Doctypehtml>
<html>
<title>new html</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="open">click me</button>
    <script>
           var open1=document.getElementById("open")
           var n="hi";
           open1.addEventListener("click",function(){
               alert(n.length);
           });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What not found? Run the above script and you will find the value 2.